# How to query EntityFramework using generic property type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

When I call `DbSet.FirstOrDefault()` by passing a predicate that compares generic type `TId`, I get the following exception:

> unable to create a constant value of type 'system.object'. only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Interface for type being queried:

```
interface IEntity<TId>
{
    TId id { get; set; }
}
```

The exception is thrown here:

```
public virtual TEntity Get<TEntity, TId>(TId id) where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
{
    return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
}
```

The function will only work if `TId` is constrained as `struct`. How can I include `string` as supported type? If it's not possible, is it possible to accomplish the task a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for strings too:

```
public virtual TEntity Get<TEntity, TId>(TId id) 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
    where TId: IEquatable<TId>
{
    return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
}
```

Comment: How can i extend it to work for arrays of these primitives too? Ex: int[] and string[]. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can. Equality for sets (RDBMSs have no concept of arrays) is too broad and there is no direct `==`-like support for it in SQL. Consider for example `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`. Are they equal to you? Is ordering important? What about `[null, 1]` and `[null,1]`? Do you care about ternary logic here or not, etc.

Comment: I'm working with MS Sql which has Binary[] type. It gets converted to System.Byte[].

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Find` method:

```
public virtual TEntity Get<TEntity, TId>(TId id) where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
{
    return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it works, but it fails for cases where the primary key is a composite key.

Comment: It is strange, how did you try it? `dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id1, id2);`?

Comment: Just as you mentioned in your post. It's just that, using `Find()`, you can't choose to use just one of the keys.